# Unexplainable syntax error on a timestamp in a psql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, syntax-error

I am having a syntax error on a psql query which is really strange, as my syntax seems right

```sql
INSERT INTO functionMonitoring (function, startDate, endDate, type, severity, status, text) values('test', 2019-07-16 17:04:53.866, 2019-07-16 17:04:53.866, 'process', 'INFORMATION', 'OK', 'Some random stuff');
```

This is my query, but typing it in my psql console gives this :

```sql
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "17"
LINE 1: ...severity, status, text) values('test', 2019-07-16 17:04:53.8...
                                                             ^
```

I don't understand why this happens. It is not a type problem as I already checked for each column's type and my table already holds similar data. Here is one exemple line already in my table

```sql
 id |    function    |          startdate           |           enddate            |  type   | severity | status |                  text
----+----------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+----------+--------+----------------------------------------
  4 | DBReaderWindow | Tue Jul 16 16:15:41.144 2019 | Tue Jul 16 16:15:42.779 2019 | process | LOW      | OK     | Function fully executed with no errors
```

I hope I gave enough information to resolve the problem, thank you for your help !

Comment: You should use  single quotes for those timestamp values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a single quote to start the string literal that contains your timestamp:

```
INSERT ... VALUES ('test', '2019-07-16 17:04:53.8', ...)
                           ^                     ^
```

Without them, PostgreSQL interprets `2019-07-16` as an arithmetic expression (equivalent to 1996) and does not expect the following `17`.

Comment: This worked, thank you ! I was sure that I did not use quotes on my dates on previous queries, but I looked again and they had quotes, I don't know why I thought it worked without quotes. Thank you for your help !